# Electricity units calculator

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, units-of-measurement

I'm basically using functions and if else if statements to build an electricity reading calculator.

The units given is 1236 which is a parameter of the function called elecReading. This will be used as the amount of units used and it will calculate the amount that must be paid.

However, the first 0-500 units are billed at $1 per unit. The next 500-1000 units are billed at $1.10 a unit, and over 1000 units are billed at $3.20 a unit. For example, if I used 1000 units, my bill would be $1050.

I'm unsure how I can get this working without breaking down 1236 into singular numbers manually. How can I write a calculator like this with JavaScript?

Obviously I'm not asking for the complete answer, but a push in the right direction would be very helpful at this stage!

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?  It's a perfectly good question.

Comment: Suppose I have used 1000 units.  Does that mean my bill is $500 + $550?  Or is my bill $1100?

Comment: Brad from what I've been told it would be $1050

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The static version would be something like:

```
var UNIT_PRICE_1001_OVER = 3.20;
var UNIT_PRICE_501_1000 = 1.10;
var UNIT_PRICE_UNDER_500 = 1.00;
function elecReading(units) {
    var price = 0;

    if (units > 1000) {
        price += (units-1000) * UNIT_PRICE_1001_OVER;
        units = 1000;
    }
    if (units > 500) {
        price += (units - 500) * UNIT_PRICE_501_1000;
        units = 500;
    }
    price += units * UNIT_PRICE_UNDER_500;

    return price;
}
```

This is assuming the unit price ranges are 1-500, 501-1000, 1001-Inf. Obviously this can be done more generally / with less hardcoding, using a list of objects representing a price range + price per unit in said range.

Comment: Ugh, corrected a big bug, there shouldn't have been any `else` statements there. Obviously units from all price ranges have to be counted.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply device power (in kW) by usage time (in hours).
This gives energy consumption in kWh.
Multiply energy consumption by cost per kWh.
Result is the total cost of electricity for the device.

Answer (score -1):

Try following function. Assuming peak rates are from units 1000+, medium rates from 501-1000, and offpeak rates from 0-500.

You could change the variables names as per your requirements/understanding.

**EDITED:**
While loop is added to keep reducing total units until they are greater than 1000

```
       function elecReading(units){

        var totalUnits=units;
        var offPeakRate=1;
        var mediumRate=1.10;
        var peakRate=3.20;
        var totalCharges=0;

        if(totalUnits>1000){
            PeakUnits = totalUnits-1000;
            totalCharges = totalCharges + (PeakUnits * peakRate);
            totalUnits = 1000;
        }

        if(totalUnits > 500){
            totalUnits = totalUnits-500;
            totalCharges =  totalCharges + (totalUnits * mediumRate);
        }  

        totalCharges = totalCharges + (totalUnits * offPeakRate); 

        return totalCharges;
    } 
  console.log(elecReading(2000));
```

Comment: This is hilariously incorrect. (Consider what happens when `2000` units are used up.)

Comment: @millimoose: good catch, i didn't realise it earlier.. how about it now?

Comment: That's only correct for `2000`, when the while loop runs twice. If you try higher numbers, like `elecReading(3000)`, it will end up counting several of the "peak" units twice (or more times). You simply can't keep deducting 1000 units while increasing the price, you **must** set the remaining units to 1000 once you've processed all but the 1000 left.